# SQL Converting from scientific notion to string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to convert a column in a table of floats so that they don't show up as scientific notation. I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Update TABLE
SET YTD = STR(YTD,12,2)
```

Doesn't have any effect as I still get values of 2.834566E+07 in the column.

Here is the full code:

```
declare @app_cur CURSOR
declare @Current_PV_Value float
declare @Current_Tagname varchar(100)
DECLARE @Year INT;
DECLARE @JanDate Datetime
DECLARE @FebDate Datetime
DECLARE @MarDate Datetime
DECLARE @AprDate Datetime
DECLARE @MayDate Datetime
DECLARE @JunDate Datetime
DECLARE @JulDate Datetime
DECLARE @AugDate Datetime
DECLARE @SepDate Datetime
DECLARE @OctDate Datetime
DECLARE @NovDate Datetime
DECLARE @DecDate Datetime
DECLARE @Date SMALLDATETIME;
SET @Date = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(4), @Year), 112);


SET @Year = 2014;


SET @JanDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year+1 AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '02' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
SET @FebDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year+1 AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '03' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
SET @MarDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year+1 AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '04' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
SET @AprDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '05' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
SET @MayDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '06' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
SET @JunDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '07' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
SET @JulDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '08' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
SET @AugDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '09' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
SET @SepDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '10' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
SET @OctDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '11' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
SET @NovDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '12' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
SET @DecDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year+1 AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '01' +  '01' + ' 00:05:00'
                AS DATETIME)
PRINT 'Opening cursor.'
    SET @app_cur = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
    SELECT   [Tagname2]
    FROM     PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals


    -- Open cursor 1 for iteration.
    OPEN @app_cur

    -- Fetch the first record.
    FETCH NEXT FROM @app_cur INTO   @Current_Tagname


    -- Iterate each record.
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
                --clear PV value
                set @Current_PV_Value = null
                --January Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @JanDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@JanDate) 
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Jan] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Jan] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                --February Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @FebDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@FebDate) 
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Feb] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Feb] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                Print 'tagname: '+@Current_Tagname
                Print 'value: '+ cast(@Current_PV_Value as varchar(50))
                --March Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @MarDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@MarDate) 
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Mar] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Mar] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                --April Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @AprDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@AprDate) 
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Apr] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Apr] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                --May Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @MayDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@MayDate)
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [May] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [May] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                --June Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @JunDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@JunDate) 
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Jun] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Jun] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                --July Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @JulDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@JulDate) 
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Jul] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Jul] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                --August Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @AugDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@AugDate) 
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Aug] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Aug] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                --September Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @SepDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@SepDate) 
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Sep] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Sep] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Sep] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                --October Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @OctDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@OctDate) 
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Oct] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Oct] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                --November Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @NovDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@NovDate) 
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Nov] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Nov] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
                --December Data
                SELECT   TOP 1 @Current_PV_Value = [Value]
                FROM     [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
                WHERE    [TagName] = @Current_Tagname
                  AND    wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
                  AND    wwVersion = 'Latest'
                  AND    [DateTime] >= @DecDate
                  AND    [DateTime] <= dateadd(minute,5,@DecDate) 
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC

                if @Current_PV_Value is not null
                Begin
                        -- Update the return set with our phase number value.
                        UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Dec] = @Current_PV_Value
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                end
                if @Current_PV_Value is null
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE  PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
                        SET     [Dec] = 0
                        WHERE   CURRENT OF @app_cur
                END
        FETCH NEXT FROM @app_cur INTO    @Current_Tagname
    END--End of cursor 1 logic

    -- Close and dispose of the cursor.
    CLOSE @app_cur
    DEALLOCATE @app_cur

--Year to Date Totals
UPDATE PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals 

    SET [YTD] = (ISNULL([Jan],0) + ISNULL([Feb],0)+ ISNULL([Mar],0) + ISNULL([Apr],0) + ISNULL([May],0) + ISNULL([Jun],0) + ISNULL([Jul],0) + ISNULL([Aug],0) + ISNULL([Sep],0) + ISNULL([Oct],0) + ISNULL([Nov],0) + ISNULL([Dec],0))

Update PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
SET Apr = round(apr,1),
May = round(may,1),
Jun = round(jun,1),
Jul = round(jul,1),
Aug = round(aug,1),
Sep = round(sep,1),
Oct = round(oct,1),
Nov = round(nov,1),
[Dec] = round(dec,1),
Jan = round(jan,1),
Feb = round(feb,1),
Mar = round(mar,1),
YTD = round(ytd,1)

Update PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
    SET YTD = str(cast(YTD as real))
Select str(cast(YTD as real)) from PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals

select * from PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN Developer Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9753eadd-5677-4ed9-8942-b3528785253b/convert-from-scientific-notation):

```
select str(cast(YTD as real) ) from TABLE
```

So if the results from the above look right:

```
Update TABLE 
SET YTD = str(cast(YTD as real) )
```

Edit: It turns out that you need to explicitly tell SQL that this is what you actually want to do:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION UpdateScinot

Update TABLE 
SET YTD = str(cast(YTD as real) )

COMMIT TRANSACTION UpdateScinot
GO
```

Comment: That seems to have the correct output with the select statement. However when I do the Update statement and then do a select * from table it still shows the original?

Comment: Try the query above @user3532047

Comment: Tried the new one. Still showing the original value when doing a select * on the entire table.

Comment: @user3532047 Updated it again, I'm not used to working with SQL Server.

Comment: Still missing something. no change.

Comment: I'm just going to add some stupid questions to eliminate any other mistakes. Are you sure you're running the update and select queries against the same table? You're not using a `USE [myDBname]` or anything like that in one of the queries? Are you mixing MSSQL Management Studio actions and regular SQL queries in text form?

Comment: Just posted the full code for this query. The last statements are where I'm working on this issue. You may notice the rest of the query is probably not very efficient but I'm new to SQL and everything works as intended so far. Just want to focus on this one issue.